# A more elegant solution to Ruby Koans' triangle.rb

Tags: ruby

I have been working through Ruby Koans and made it to about_triangle_project.rb in which you are required to write the code for a method, triangle.

Code for these items are found here:

https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/blob/master/koans/about_triangle_project.rb

https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/blob/master/koans/triangle.rb

In triangle.rb, I created the following method:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  if ((a == b) && (a == c) && (b == c))
    return :equilateral
  elsif ((a == b) || (a == c) || (b == c))
    return :isosceles
  else
    return :scalene
  end
end
```

I know from reading Chris Pine's "Learn to Program" there is always more than one way to do things. Although the above code works, I can't help but think there is a more elegant way of doing this. Would anyone out there be willing to offer their thoughts on how they might make such a method more efficient and compact?

Another thing I am curious about is why, for determining an equilateral triangle, I was unable to create the condition of (a == b == c). It is the proof for an equilateral triangle but Ruby hates the syntax. Is there an easy explanation as to why this is?

Comment: `==` is an operator that accepts to values (like `*` or `/` ). it returns `true` or `false`. it is illegal as to not cause confusion (e.g `1 == 1 == 1` would evaluate to `false` as it is equivalent to `(1 == 1) == 1`).

Comment: You could've saved a bit of code by using the transitive property for `:equilateral`: (a == b) && (b == c)

Comment: Python supports the "a == b == c" syntax (or even "a < b <= c"), but among programming languages that is an exception rather than a rule.

Answer (score 59):

There is an easy explanation for why that is:

`==` in Ruby is an operator, which performs a specific function. Operators have rules for determining what order they're applied in — so, for example, `a + 2 == 3` evaluates the addition before the equality check. But only one operator at a time is evaluated. It doesn't make sense to have two equality checks next to each other, because an equality check evaluates to `true` or `false`. Some languages allow this, but it still doesn't work right, because then you'd be evaluating `true == c` if `a` and `b` were equal, which is obviously not true even if a == b == c in mathematical terms.

As for a more elegant solution:

```
case [a,b,c].uniq.size
when 1 then :equilateral
when 2 then :isosceles
else        :scalene
end
```

Or, even briefer (but less readable):

```
[:equilateral, :isosceles, :scalene].fetch([a,b,c].uniq.size - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, chuck!  I haven't reached using case, uniq or fetch yet in koans, but that is extremely cool (and why I love Ruby!).

Comment: +1 for `uniq.size`; that's elegant. Interesting that you chose to use `fetch`, as `[...][[...].uniq.size]` is valid.

Comment: @Phrogz: I wrote it that way at first, but it was just egregiously unreadable, like the kind of Perl code that people always make fun of, so I figured `fetch` at least approximated something I'd want to read.

Comment: I came up with this code: `[nil, :equilateral, :isosceles, :scalene][[a,b,c].uniq.size]` but I think yours is a little more readable.

Comment: Great stuff, but note the two typos (isosceles & scalene) in the briefer solution. Too few changes to edit.

Comment: @Jamie Schembri: Fixed. Thanks for that. Love that I got "equilateral" right but not the much shorter "scalene".

Answer (score 12):

Another approach:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  a, b, c = [a, b, c].sort
  raise TriangleError if a <= 0 or a + b <= c
  return :equilateral if a == c
  return :isosceles if a == b or b == c
  return :scalene
end
```

Comment: +1 Clever use of the ordering to avoid unnecessary comparisons.

Comment: I had to add 
    class TriangleError < StandardError
    end
to the end for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  if a == b && a == c                # transitivity => only 2 checks are necessary
    :equilateral
  elsif a == b || a == c || b == c   # == operator has the highest priority
    :isosceles
  else
    :scalene                         # no need for return keyword
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, glebm! (And for the answer above, too.)

Answer (score 6):

I borrowed Chuck's cool uniq.size technique and worked it into an oo solution. Originally I just wanted to extract the argument validation as a guard clause to maintain single responsibility principle, but since both methods were operating on the same data, I thought they belonged together in an object.

```
# for compatibility with the tests
def triangle(a, b, c)
  t = Triangle.new(a, b, c)
  return t.type
end

class Triangle
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @sides = [a, b, c].sort
    guard_against_invalid_lengths
  end

  def type
    case @sides.uniq.size
    when 1 then :equilateral
    when 2 then :isosceles
    else :scalene
    end
  end

  private
  def guard_against_invalid_lengths
    if @sides.any? { |x| x <= 0 }
      raise TriangleError, "Sides must be greater than 0"
    end

    if @sides[0] + @sides[1] <= @sides[2]
      raise TriangleError, "Not valid triangle lengths"    
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is great answer to the Tests portion of the about_triangle_project_2.rb as well.  I copy/pasta'd your solution which was much more elegant that my machine code version.

Answer (score 5):

```
class TriangleError < StandardError
end

def triangle(a, b, c)
  sides = [a,b,c].sort

  raise TriangleError if sides.first <= 0 || sides[2] >= sides[1] + sides[0]
  return :equilateral if sides.uniq.length  == 1
  return :isosceles if sides.uniq.length  == 2
  :scalene
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  sides = [a, b, c].sort
  raise TriangleError, "Invalid side #{sides[0]}" unless sides[0] > 0
  raise TriangleError, "Impossible triangle" if sides[0] + sides[1] <= sides[2]
  return [:scalene, :isosceles, :equilateral][ 3 - sides.uniq.size ]
end
```

Comment: I like that this fully leverages the sort to give more precise error feedback and is the shortest and easiest to read.  Does not need the return though.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. I didn't know about `uniq` - so coming from smalltalk (ages ago) I used:

```
require 'set'
def triangle(a, b, c)
  case [a, b, c].to_set.count
    when 1 then :equilateral
    when 2 then :isosceles
    else :scalene
  end
end
```

Comment: I took a look for a more elegant solution than what I had implemented and found this post a year and a half after the fact...  But I have to say I really like this solution.  It's a nice clean approach that is also very readable; kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Coming from the matlab world, I am used to array functions 'any' and 'all', and was happy enough to find them in Ruby. So:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  eqs = [a==b, a==c, b==c]
  eqs.all?? :equilateral : eqs.any?? :isosceles : :scalene
end
```

No idea whether that's optimal though, in terms of readability, computation time... (ruby noob).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  return :equilateral if a == b and b == c
  return :isosceles if ( a == b or b == c or a == c )
  return :scalene
end
```